# java while loop stale

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading

I have a application which is a multithread `Spring boot application`. The business use-case is, it reads data from mysql and perform various task.

The whole logic of reading from database is written in try block which is inside a infinite while loop.

`consumeDatabaseData()` of `DatabaseService.java` is called from the run method of main Spring boot class as shown below.

I have this kind of many loop running which reads data from `mysql` and perform task.

The problem is that, the given while loop looks stale, i.e I have data in my mysql table but It looks that it is not reading from mysql as I am not receiving any logs in console with in while loop.

But My sservice is running as I am receiving logs in console which is reading data from mysql.

I am posting my code below, what may be the possible cause.

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseService databaseService;
    public static void main(String...args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        databaseService.consumeDatabaseData();

    }

}
```

**DatabaseService.java**:

```
 public class DatabaseService {


        public void consumeDatabaseData() {

            while(true) {
                try {
                    // Read rows from database e.g Mysql and apply various business logics
System.out.println("I am reading data: " + Instant.now());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // do nothing
                    // retry again
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At a glance, is your `catch` block actually empty? It's possible that there's an exception being thrown every time, but you're silently ignoring them.

Comment: Do you have some logging in the `catch` block? Just to make sure no `Exception` is thrown either when trying to read data from the database or when applying the business logic.

Comment: What do you mean by the loop being "stale" ? Do you mean "stalled" instead, i.e the loop is stuck?

Comment: I am Logging in Catch Block but no Error Log is printed, means no Error is generated.
Data is being read as it is Loggedin console, and No Error is printed in Catch Block as well as the Try Block.
Logs are applied in try as well as catch block, but none of them are printed.
Application is Running but i think the while loop is not Running.